# Unable to set workbook with open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have an open workbook from it I want to fetch data in another workbook.

My code is:

```
Dim wbsource as workbook
Dim wssource as worksheet
Dim wbtarget as workbook
Dim wstarget as worksheet

set wbsource = workbooks("D:/test.xlsx")
```

Even though my source workbook name and address is correct it's giving subscript out of range error.

If I close my source workbook and use

```
Set wbsource = workbooks.open ("D:/test.xlsx")
```

it works fine.

Comment: When you set your open workbook use the name of the file not the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try matching the name in the `Set` command to the caption name:

```
Sub SetupWorkbookObject()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks("sample.xlsm")
    MsgBox wb.Name
End Sub
```

[image]

Note:

Neither the `Set` command nor the window caption have the full filespec, only the filename.

Comment: Source workbook keeps on updating from other source once it's open. So what is the name of that temporary file? Before its saved?